# C Program closes after giving input

Tags: c

So I have just started learning c, whenever I give input and press enter my .exe file closes anything to counter that?
Code:-

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    float bp,da,hra,grpay;
    printf("\nEnter Basic Salary of Ramesh: ");
    scanf("%f", &bp);
    getchar();
    da = 0.4*bp;
    hra = 0.2* bp;
    grpay = bp + da + hra;
    printf("Basic Salary of Ramesh = %f\n", bp);
    printf("Dearness Allowance = %f\n", da);
    printf("House rent allowance = %f\n",hra);
    printf("Gross Pay of Ramesh is %f\nz", grpay);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

I also tried getchar() but that did not work, I want the application output to stay there after pressing enter and proceed to the next line of the code

Comment: Just `sleep(20)` to stall.

Comment: i am getting an error of ```implicit declaration of function sleep```

Comment: As always you need to include the right header file, in this case probably `#include <unistd.h>`.

Comment: it works but my program does not proceed to the next line and run the specific code

Comment: `sleep()` is not in the standard C library.

Comment: @tadman this is more likely to be Windows than not.

Comment: OT: regarding: `da = 0.4*bp;` and `hra = 0.2* bp;`  Those literals `0,4` and `0,2` are `double` values.  To make them `float` values, append a trailing `f` such as: `0.4f` and `0.2f`

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. For Windows there's always [`Sleep()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-sleep).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the last call to;

```
getchar();
```

will not do the job, by itself.  Suggest:

```
int ch;
while( (ch = getchar() ) != EOF && ch != '\n' ){;}
getchar();
```